# Ckeditor greyed out when on cloudflare

Tags: ckeditor

I cant use ckeditor when on cloudflare. As soon as I edit the node...I get empty wysiwyg editor. Same for comments.
And the console error is

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ebdesign.com/node/add/article' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.ebdesign.com/themes/contrib/at_theme/at_core/ckeditor/skins/mimic/editor.css?t=r9mmak'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It works fine on regular hosting without cloudflare...

Comment: here is the htaccess file

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/bq98anqm